OneNote - remove section out from a Section Group
It may be a very basic question, but I have not been able to do that..
How do you move a section back / out of a section group.
I moved a section into a Section Group, now I can't find a way to move it back..
Is there a proper way to do that ..
Here, I have a section in "Ideas" - section group



How to move this "holidays" back from Ideas Section Group, to be placed adjacent to the other sections like Weekdays, Notes.. in the My NoteBook.. Any ideas, would by highly appreciable,

I came here looking for answers too but was able to figure it out through some trial and error.
Click and hold onto the section you want to move out of the Section Group and into your Notebook, then drag the section over the Notebook name and "drop" it into the Notebook that you want it to be in. If you have multiple Notebooks, it might take a second for your list of Notebooks to show up.
Best,
Chad
